# Execute analysis in SonarQube from Maven but not storing the results in database

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I am developing a new project in Eclipse and I have to analyze it with SonarQube. I am doing a lot of changes in the code and analysing it, but I wouldn't like that SonarQube store all the results in it's database (they are temporary versions). Is there any option for it?

I have configured my pom file like [sonarQube official config](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/):

```
<profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.host.url>
              http://myserver:9000
            </sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

It connects with Sonar and execute the analysis ok, but I am storing lots of useless executions in SonarQube.

Regards

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you working on a branch? Apart from that why using a profile? can handled via command line without any profile... Using CI ?

Comment: I am working with a project that I need to clean of Sonar warnings. I would like to make a change in the code and check if the warning in Sonar has desapeared, but if I invoke sonar:sonar (maven o command line, no differences) Sonar stores in it's database all these executions. I would like to know if there is an option/parameter to invoke Sonar but telling it not to store de result.

Comment: Sorry isn't that the idea of SonarQube to see the improvement over the time? You can of course after finally made it reinstall the whole SonarQube installation or delete the projects in SonarQube ...(if you are allowed to) ... or use a SonarQube in a Docker Container for the steps towards the target ? ...

Comment: I know this is the idea, but in my project they like to keep results only for the stable versions. I tried to install sonarlint in local but it gives me problems with eclipse, so I was looking for alternatives. I remember in other project (long time ago) we used Sonar, from maven, with a parameter for that, but I am not able to remember which was.

Comment: I found the parameter 'sonar.analysis.mode= preview' but is not longer supported by Sonar. Thank you

Comment: Sorry the idea of keep results only for stable versions does not really make sense... If you don't use a dockerized version of sonarqube etc. ... If sonarlint for Eclipse does not work use the one in IDEA IntelliJ works ... Sonar from Maven? Does not exist...

Answer (score 0):

You might get some value from the SonarLint Eclipse plugin: https://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse .

With this, you might be able to iterate on local changes before submitting a full sonarqube scan.

Comment: I tried it, but I can not get it to work with the WebLogic plugin. Thank you